# How to return a string from map object and send to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Hey guys how can I get the value of this object "position" as a string, so I can pass it to firebase database? I tried different ways.
In my console.log it returns this value: Map(1) {'1_1' => 4}
But firebase is not reading it, so I tried to do it toString(position), and it goes to firebase like that:

> records:"[object Undefined]"

I just need something like that **1_1 : 4**
My code:

```
function updateValueDb(index) {
  const key = `${turno}_${index + 1}`;
  const value = 4;
  const position = new Map([[key, value]]);
  console.log(position); //output : Map(1) {'1_1' => 4}
  set(ref(db, "records/", setor.flap), position);
}
```

Comment: why can't you just do `${key} : ${value}` ?

Comment: set(ref(db, "records/", setor.flap), `${key} : ${value}`);

In firebase it returns : 
`records : "1_4 : 4" `
I'm looking for something like that:  
`"1_4" : "4"`

Comment: Then use `{ key : value }`

Comment: `set(ref(db, "records/", setor.flap), { key : value });` It is not returning the key values, the result = `key
:
4`

Comment: what is this `setor.flap`? use { [key]: value }

Comment: It's a path, just like that: `firebase/records/flap/` and then `1_1 :  4`

Comment: `{ [key]: value }` it's working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `Map` object first, nor stringify it, and calling `.toString` on an object `position` should output something like `"[object Map]"`, it won't output what you expect.

It seems you want to pass an object with the `key` value *as* the key and the `value` as the value. Use an Object initializer with [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), i.e. `{ [key]: value }`.

```js
const turno = 1, index = 0;

const key = `${turno}_${index + 1}`;
const value = 4;

const position = {
  [key]: value,
};

console.log(position);
```

Code

```
function updateValueDb(index) {
  const key = `${turno}_${index + 1}`;
  const value = 4;

  const position = {
    [key]: value,
  };

  set(ref(db, "records/", setor.flap), position);
}
```